# InvokeMember give a different result than direct call

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I'm calling Shell.BrowseForFolder in VB.NET because I need to pass an arbitrary path in the rootFolder argument. So I instanciate an objet like this:

```
Dim shellType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application")
Dim shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType)
```

Then I call:

```
Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, message, &H241, rootFolder)
```

It does not work as expected (the root folder F: is not used)

[image: Direct call]

But if I use reflection with the same arguments:

```
Dim folder = shellType.InvokeMember("BrowseForFolder", _
  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, shell, New Object() {0, message, &H241, _
  rootFolder})
```

It works!

[image: Reflection]

But for me the 2 calls (InvokeMember and direct call) should produce similar results (the arguments are identical). What's happening?

**Edit:**

In fact, it works if I call ToString() or if I put a litteral:

```
Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, message, &H241, rootFolder.ToString())
```

or

```
Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, message, &H241, "F:")
```

But it doesn't work if rootFolder is an argument, eg:

```
Function BrowseForFolder(ByVal message As String, ByVal rootFolder As String) As String
    Dim shellType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application")
    Dim shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType)
    Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, message, &H241, rootFolder)
    If folder Is Nothing Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Return folder.Self.Path
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

only way for me to reproduce this issue under windows 7 64bits with vs 2012 is to have an invalid `rootFolder` like an empty string or crap data in that variable.

can you do a breakpoint on that line:

```
   Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, message, &H241, rootFolder)
```

and check what is `rootFolder` ?

found a way try this;

```
  Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, message, &H241, rootFolder.ToString())
```

my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rootFolder As Object = "f:"
    Dim shellType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application")
    Dim shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType)
    Dim folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "message", &H241, rootFolder.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: Agreed, can't repro here either on vs2010., same OS.

Comment: I'm working with VS 2010 on a Windows 7 64 bit OS. rootFolder is a string initialized with "F:". This disk exists on my computer.

Comment: @Maxence, i think i found how to fix it, i was able to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Maxence replace rootFolder with rootFolder.ToString() seem weird but it work.

Comment: @Maxence and make rootFolder an Object type, not string.

Comment: @Maxence, for that one... ask microsoft, i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use folderBrowserDialog directly:

```
Dim f As New FolderBrowserDialog
f.SelectedPath = "f:"
f.ShowDialog()
```

Though I can't see how to get it to *only* show F:

Comment: I'm using Shell.BrowseForFolder because FolderBrowserDialog only take a SpecialFolder in his RootFolder property.

Comment: Sure - it is, after all, a bizarre limitation.